# Referencing from one view to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I am learning to use Visual Studio, C# and Entity Framework Core and I try to create an WPF to edit entries in a database. At the moment I work with the Adventureworks2014 database.

I have a Datagrid which gets it's data from a view i created in Microsoft SQL Server Management.

```
public void PopulateDataGrid()
{
        using (var db = new Adventureworks2014Context())
        {                      
              DG1.ItemsSource = db.SmallView.ToList<SmallView>();
        }
}
```

When I double click on an entry in my Datagrid, I want the app to open a new window in which the data of the person is shown. Depending on the state of a checkbox I want to use other views

So I want to chose a person, get the persons ID and use this ID in the different View to get the Data I want.

This is what I came up with (which does not work):

```
 private void DG1DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DG1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {                
                using (Adventureworks2014Context db = new Adventureworks2014Context())
                {
                   
                    SmallView smallView = (SmallView)DG1.SelectedItem;    //getting the Data of a person
                    txtIdCreate.Text = Convert.ToString(smallView.BusinessEntityId);        //just to check if i get an ID       

                                  
                    NoAdminView noAdminView = new NoAdminView();
                    db.NoAdminView.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BusinessEntityId == smallView.BusinessEntityId);                 
                    TxtFirstName.Text = noAdminView.FirstName; //checking if i get anything from the other view
    

                }

            }
```

My Textfield is empty, so i don't get the right reference from the view.
I could also use a different view with all the entries i need/will need and could show only specific columns but that is not the approach i try to use because I think it can be really useful when i am able to "switch between views" when I want to, so e.g. the bigger views with lots of columns are only used when needed. Also it could be quite efficient when the only thing i need to do is changing the ItemSource.

When i am here wrong as well it would be great to know why this thought is not the right one.

Would be happy about some feedback.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use EF-core to get data from the databse.

I suggest that you can use database-first.

First, please install the following nuget-package.

[image]

Second, please use the following command in the package console.

```
 PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server name;Database=AdventureWorks2014;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Third, after generating a folder named `Models`, please try the following code in the wpf app.

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateDataGrid();
        }
        public void PopulateDataGrid()
        {
            using (var db = new AdventureWorks2014Context())
            {
                var listentity = db.BusinessEntities.ToList<BusinessEntity>();
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = listentity;

            }
        }
        private void dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGrid1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                using (AdventureWorks2014Context db = new AdventureWorks2014Context())
                {

                    BusinessEntity entity = (BusinessEntity)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
                    txtID.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.BusinessEntityId);        //just to check if i get an ID       


                     Person p= db.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BusinessEntityId == entity.BusinessEntityId);
                     txtFirstName.Text = p.FirstName; //checking if i get anything from the other view


                }
            }
        }
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That works. Great. I even see where my mistake was.